# How to validate a dropdown menu using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have three drop down menus in a single page. I want to validate all the drop down items in a single click. Any suggestions would help.

Here is my code for a drop down validation:

HTML

```
<select id="ddlView">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>  

<input type="button" onclick="Validate()" value="select" />
```

JS

```
function Validate()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("ddlView");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    if(strUser==0)
    {
        alert("Please select a user");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of validation to do, then use a validation library like:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/.

You have to be more precise regarding your question, what is your concrete problem here? Or shall we guess...

Comment: want to validate drop down ...and i have three drop down ,dono how to validate for three in single page

Comment: With jquery you can do this: _http://jsfiddle.net/fyv2L7o2/_ [It's only a possible solution]

Comment: For trivial code like this you really don't need to pull in jquery

Comment: @RobinHellemans sure, but if you're already using jQuery, why not make your life easier? And to be fair, the OP tagged it...

Comment: Ah my apologies I didn't see the jquery tag, in that case you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your selects a class and just loop through them validating each as you go:

```js
// bind an event handler to the button
$('.slectValBtn').click(function(){
   // remove all errors 
   $('.slectVal').removeClass('hasErrors');
   $('.error').remove();
   // create a var to track any errors
    var errors = 0
    // loop through all your elements with the class `slectVal`
    $('.slectVal').each(function(){
       // get the minimum value fo this element
       var min = $(this).data('min-val');
       // get the custom message for this element
       var msg = '<br><span class="error">'+$(this).data('error-msg')+min+'</span>';
       // check the element's value
       if( $(this).val() < min ){
          // if i the value fails validation, add 1 to our errors count
          errors++;
         $(this).addClass('hasErrors');
         // add error message
         $(msg).insertAfter( $(this) );
       }
    
    }); 
    // after looping all elements, check our error count
    if(errors > 0){
      // had errors
      alert('All values must be greater than 0');
    }
    else{
      // no errors
      alert('All values valid!');
      
    }
});
```

```css
.hasErrors{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
.error{
  
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlView1" class="slectVal" data-error-msg="Pick an option equal to or greater than " data-min-val="1">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">test1</option>
        <option value="2">test2</option>
        <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select> <br>
    <select id="ddlView2" class="slectVal" data-error-msg="Pick an option equal to or greater than " data-min-val="1">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">test1</option>
        <option value="2">test2</option>
        <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select>   <br>
    <select id="ddlView3" class="slectVal" data-error-msg="Pick an option equal to or greater than " data-min-val="1">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">test1</option>
        <option value="2">test2</option>
        <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select>   <br>

    <input type="button" class="slectValBtn" value="select" />
```

Comment: DelightedD0D....thanks for the code,its working fine. How to add error message under the dropdown when error occurs

Comment: @stark Updated, though as Ledgends mentioned, if you're goona go that far, you might want to look into a library like http://jqueryvalidation.org/ : )

Answer (score 0):

Inline event registration is a bad practice, you should probably do this:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=button]').addEventListener('click', Validate, false);
```

As to your original question, you could just get all selects in one statement and then validate them one by one:

```
var selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName('select'); 
//Validation logic
```

If you want to be more specific as to which select lists (in case you have more than those 3 on your page) you want to validate, try using `document.querySelectorAll` or use jquery's selector.

Or you could off course use a class for all of your selects you want to validate and then select those like other users have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a class to all <select> elements of your form. Then you can use the `querySelectorAll` function to get all elements with this class. `querySelectorAll` is more browser compatible than `getElementsByClassName` according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector). It works like CSS selectors (or JQuery selectors)

```
// get all <select> tags with the "cantBeZero" class
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("select.cantBeZero");
var emptyElements = [];
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; ++i) {
    if(elements[i].options[elements[i].selectedIndex]].value == 0) {
        emptyElements.push(elements[i]);
    }
}
// emptyElements is now an array of all incorrect drop-down menus.
```

Comment: Thought `querySelectorAll` doesn't return a live nodelist like `getElementsByClassName` does, off course that depends on the op's use case